Implementation of MATLAB function in c#
I wrote a function as follows in MATLAB:
function [z] = zarb(a, b)

z = a * b;

end

I fixed this code with "dll" and added it in "Add References".
And I used it with the following code in C#:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using zarb;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 m = new Class1();
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            MWArray n1 = a;
            MWArray n2 = b;
            MWArray javab;
            javab = m.zarb(n1, n2);
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(javab));
        }
    }
}


When I ran it I got this error:
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'zarb.Class1' threw an exception.
BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
My MATLAB version is 2022a and .NET version is 4.7.
What is the cause of this error?

Did you literally just change the file extension from .m to .dll? That won't ever work. You would have to compile your MATLAB code into a dll, probably using MATLAB Coder, as mentioned here https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/452267-can-i-generate-dlls-using-matlab-coder#answer_367308

BadImageFormatException are commonly caused by 32/64 bit conflicts, so check the project settings. While .Net code is typically platform agnostic, your dll may be a wrapper around a native, platform specific library. I would also consider just porting the matlab code to c#, this avoids a bunch of dependency problems, and many of the more common matrix and math functions are available from libraries like math.net

Numerous answers agree with Jonas
